# Running spark-client snap, executor pod won't start up on specific node

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm running microk8s (installed via `snap install microk8s --classic`) across a local multinode cluster and [spark-client](https://snapcraft.io/spark-client) (installed via `snap install spark-client --edge`). Two of the nodes are WSL2 (Ubuntu) on Windows 11. I'm now adding a laptop running Ubuntu node. When I try to run `spark-client.spark-shell ...`, it will spin up executors successfully on the two WSL nodes, but it fails on the new laptop node. I know the laptop node is capable of running pods successfully because an hdfs pod is successfully running there.

`spark-shell` immediately deletes and creates a new pod when it fails, so it's hard to see the error information. I was able to capture a log and it was only one line:
`error: unknown command "executor", see 'pebble help'.`

I notice that in the configuration for those pods there is an argument: executor, so that might be where that's coming from. But why would one node start up differently?

The image is: ghcr.io/canonical/charmed-spark:3.4.0-22.04_edge . I was able to run it directly.

Any ideas on how to resolve or further troubleshoot this?

Note: I did see 2 other questions here that are similar, but they do not have this particular error message, so I think this question is distinct.

Update: I just noticed in the node details, the sha256 is different across the nodes for that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news and bad news...

I deleted the images on all the nodes:

`microk8s.ctr images delete ghcr.io/canonical/charmed-spark:3.4.0-22.04_edge`

to force it to pull the latest.

Now all the nodes behave the same. They all fail. I'll assume that some bug was introduced last week. The latest edge release was last week (6/8), after I pulled the image for the old nodes, but before I pulled for the new node.

Mystery solved, though no solution, because I can't pull an older version via snap because it's on the same channel. I'll find something else to use.

Filed bug: https://github.com/canonical/spark-client-snap/issues/68
There's an immediate workaround in the bug conversation, though it sounds like they'll have a fix out soon.